# Docker build on Windows failed to establish a new connection Errno 11001 getaddrinfo failed

Tags: docker

Docker build is failing when it gets to this step:

> RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

Some other answers suggested adding --dns or using a proxy server setting, but none of them work (--dns is an unknown flag).

This happens with all Docker Build commands.  I have tried my home network because I though my work network is causing this error.  But the same error results.  And this same build command worked 2 weeks ago.

Full test of error:

```
C:\Users\Ghassan.Hariz\Documents\_Dev\Docker\FlaskWAHelloWorld>docker build 
-f Dockerfile -t flaskhelloworld:latest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB
Step 1/7 : FROM python:3.6
3.6: Pulling from library/python
3889bb8d808b: Pull complete
6631c2d2a60c: Pull complete
3e7b18583f4b: Pull complete
adf62195c93f: Pull complete
41bbc8eda457: Pull complete
9dfc9d816cb9: Pull complete
a57794da6fe5: Pull complete
f06f2d6a9853: Pull complete
25a7926ec41d: Pull complete
Digest: 
sha256:0dab923cf03b659a25b2f3e05181bddc11e2af4577537f5050db479882c7bd53
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:3.6
 ---> 0450e8af9dc3
Step 2/7 : RUN mkdir /code
 ---> Running in 75c6959f8ee9
Directory: C:\
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        8/30/2018   7:00 AM                code
Removing intermediate container 75c6959f8ee9
 ---> 419d2d14684f
Step 3/7 : WORKDIR /code
Removing intermediate container cdcdcbe7f3fa
 ---> fcdc1433a9a6
Step 4/7 : ADD . /code/
 ---> 031143926f8f
Step 5/7 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in a3219ca48077
Collecting Flask (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 
'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection 
object at 0x00000222AFB46908>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 
11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/flask/

Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None,status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000222AFB467F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/flask/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000222AFB46518>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/flask/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000222AFB46860>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/flask/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000222AFB464E0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/flask/

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
```

No matching distribution found for Flask (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
The command 'powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1

C:\Users\Ghassan.Hariz\Documents_Dev\Docker\FlaskWAHelloWorld>docker --version
Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a

Comment: Is there anything unusual about your network environment?  Are you behind some sort of proxy or anything like that?

Comment: @DavidMaze Like I said above, I tried it using my home network and using my phone (as hotspot) because, like you, I thought it may be my work network set up.  However, the same error occurs everywhere.

Comment: If it is a network issue: how can Docker download and extract Python 3.6 but fail when getting flask?  If it is a network issue, I would think it would fail on Python as well.